# How and where should I add a check condition to see if the user is above 18 years in Django?

Tags: python, django

What I want to do is, if the user is above 18, then ask him to fill out a form ... if below 18, then ask him to fill up a different form and save the form to the database

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from app1.form import UserForm
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request,"home.html")

def formpage(request):
    form=UserForm()

    if(request.method=='POST'):
        form=UserForm(request.POST)
        if(form.is_valid()):
            form.save()
            return home(request)
    return render(request,'formpage.html',{'form':form})
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
gen_opts= [
('male','Male'),
('female', 'Female'),
]
class MyUser(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=gen_opts)
    age= models.PositiveIntegerField()
    ph.num=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    check_box = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
from app1.models import MyUser
from django import forms

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model=MyUser
        fields='__all__'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to parse the form data, and then take action based on the parsed data.

This should look something like the following:

```
if form.is_valid():
    age = form.cleaned_data['age']
    if age < 18:
        # render < 18 form
    else:
        # render >= 18 form
```